# tSQL aggregate functions and group bys

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, group-by, count

So, I can't seem to find a way to get this to work. But, what I need is as follow.

I have a table that has lets say types.

```
Type_ID, Type_Description
```

Then I have a table of Items. [Item Type is fk to type table]

```
Item_ID, Item_Type
```

Then I have a Results Table. [Item_ID is fk to Item table]

```
Result_ID, Item_ID, Cost
```

So what i am needing for output is Grouped by the Type_ID 
 - The Count of Items(can be 0), 
 - The Count of Results(Can be 0), 
 - and the sum of Cost(can be 0)

I dont have direct access to these tables. I am having to build the sql and send it to an api so I dont get to know the error simply the results if successful and error 500 if not.

Seems to be older tSQL. As List and `STRING_AGG` dont seem to be available.

EDIT: As requested - Sample Data

```
 +---------+------------------+ 
 | Type_ID | Type_Description | 
 +---------+------------------+
 |    1    |    Example 1     |
 +---------+------------------+
 |    2    |    Example 2     |
 +---------+------------------+
```

```
 +---------+---------------+ 
 | ITEM_ID |   ITEM_TYPE   | 
 +---------+---------------+
 |    1    |       1       |
 +---------+---------------+
 |    2    |       1       |
 +---------+---------------+
 |    3    |       1       |
 +---------+---------------+
 |    4    |       2       |
 +---------+---------------+
 |    5    |       2       |
 +---------+---------------+
```

```
 +-----------+---------+------+ 
 | Result_ID | Item_ID | Cost | 
 +-----------+---------+------+ 
 |     1     |    1    |  10  |
 +-----------+---------+------+
 |     2     |    1    |  20  |
 +-----------+---------+------+
 |     3     |    2    |   5  |
 +-----------+---------+------+
 |     4     |    5    |  100 |
 +-----------+---------+------+
```

Desired Output

```
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
 | Type_ID | Item_Count | Result_Count | Cost |
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
 |    1    |      3     |       3      |  35  |
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
 |    2    |      2     |       1      |  100 |
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
```

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Done

Comment: From what you explain, I think you would need to add a `Type_ID 3` and all 0 in the final results. Otherwise, you will get incorrect answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think GMB's answer was quite good, but in case there is a type with no items (something in your requirements), it will not be displayed.
So first of all let's create the input data:

```
select 1 as Type_ID, 'Example 1' as Type_Description into #type
union all
select 2, 'Example 2'
union all
select 3, 'Example 3'

select 1 Result_ID, 1 Item_ID, 10 Cost into #item
union all
select 2, 1, 20 Cost
union all
select 3, 2, 5 Cost
union all
select 4, 5, 100 Cost

select 1 Item_ID, 1 Item_Type INTO #item_type
union all
select 2, 1
union all
select 3, 1
union all
select 4, 2
union all
select 5, 2
```

Note I added also a type 3 with no items to test the no item case.

And then the query you need:

```
SELECT
    t.Type_ID, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT it.Item_ID) Item_Count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT i.Result_ID) Result_Count, 
    SUM(ISNULL(Cost, 0)) Cost
FROM #type t
LEFT JOIN #item_type it on it.Item_Type = t.Type_ID
LEFT JOIN #item i on i.Item_ID = it.Item_ID
GROUP BY t.Type_ID
```

I think it is pretty straightforward and doesn't need much explanation, but feel free to ask in the comments if necessary.

The results are just like you requested, with also a line for type 3:

```
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
 | Type_ID | Item_Count | Result_Count | Cost |
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
 |    1    |      3     |       3      |  35  |
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
 |    2    |      2     |       1      |  100 |
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
 |    3    |      0     |       0      |  0   |
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
```

You mentioned that the count of items could be 0 and also the count of results. But aren't both values always either `0`, or both `> 0`? Only in case your type-item many-to-many table doesn't have a FK, you could have that scenario. For example, if I add:

```
insert into #item_type
select 6, 3
```

Then the last row is:

```
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
 |    3    |      1     |       0      |  0   |
 +---------+------------+--------------+------+
```

I am not sure if that makes sense in your scenario, but as your post implies that items and results can be 0 independently, that confused me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can join and aggregate. Assuming that your tables are called `types`, `types_costs` and `costs`, that would be:

```
select 
    t.type_id, 
    count(distinct tc.item_id) item_count, 
    count(distinct c.result_id) result_count, 
    sum(c.cost) cost
from types t
inner join types_costs tc on tc.item_type = t.type_id
left costs c on c.item_id = tc.item_id
group by t.type_id
```

An important thing is to use a `left join` to bring the `costs` table so `item_id`s that do not exist in `costs` are not eliminated before you get a change to count them. Depending on your actual use case, you might also want a `left join` on table `types_costs`.